# How do I write a test for system login?

Tags: linux, bash, security, login, testing

I've written a Python CGI script that invokes `bash` commands, and it needs to test for a successful login on the host.

How do I write a test for that?

For example, could I create a `bash` script that tests a given username and password combination against the registered user on the host?

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the code behind the `login` program.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I hope you are encrypting the traffic to your web server so that user logins can't be sniffed off the wire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using PAM is the best solution. You can write small C code, or install python-pam package and use a python script which comes with the python-pam package. See `/usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py`

Comment: I try PAM but it didn't work. But I try again this example and it work.

Comment: In OpenSUSE 12.3 (python-pam 0.5.0-84.1.1) and 13.1 (0.5.0-87.1.2), the full path to pamtest.py is `/usr/share/doc/packages/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py` The script pamtest.py can be used to test credentials on systems using [PAM](http://linux-pam.org/) for authentication, is included in the python-pam package (which requires python), and in some distributions the full path is `/usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py`.

Answer (score 5):

The right approach to testing whether a user can log in is to actually log in as that user.

So what I recommend is to make the CGI script use [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to run `su`, pass a password and run the command that must be executed. Here's a draft of an expect script that does just this (warning: absolutely untested, and I'm not fluent in expect). Substitute in the user name, password and command (where I wrote `bob`, `swordfish` and `somecommand`); be sure to quote correctly.

```
spawn "/bin/su" "bob"
expect "Password:"
send "swordfish\r"
expect "^\\$"
send "somecommand"
expect -re "^\\$"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

If you really don't want to execute the command through a layer of `su` (for example because what you do has to be performed by the CGI process itself), then use expect to run the command `true` and check that the return status is 0.

Another approach would be to use [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) directly in your application, through [Python's PAM binding](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pam).

Comment: It is awesome, The only solution that without root access.

Comment: this works `su -c true bob && echo success` it shame that su don't accept password as argument

Comment: I tested `su` from CGI script and it need a terminal for it to work.

Comment: @jcubic It is a really stupid idea to put a password in a command line argument, because command line arguments are public on a Unix system. Removing the password would provide the same level of security as putting it in the command line. And it would be much easier to check: `/bin/true` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'C', 'Python' PAM solution quoted here, let me put the perl one too :-)

Source: http://search.cpan.org/~nikip/Authen-PAM-0.16/PAM/FAQ.pod#1._Can_I_authenticate_a_user_non_interactively?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

  use Authen::PAM;
  use POSIX qw(ttyname);

  $service = "login";
  $username = "foo";
  $password = "bar";
  $tty_name = ttyname(fileno(STDIN));

  sub my_conv_func {
    my @res;
    while ( @_ ) {
        my $code = shift;
        my $msg = shift;
        my $ans = "";

        $ans = $username if ($code == PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON() );
        $ans = $password if ($code == PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF() );

        push @res, (PAM_SUCCESS(),$ans);
    }
    push @res, PAM_SUCCESS();
    return @res;
  }

  ref($pamh = new Authen::PAM($service, $username, \&my_conv_func)) ||
         die "Error code $pamh during PAM init!";

  $res = $pamh->pam_set_item(PAM_TTY(), $tty_name);
  $res = $pamh->pam_authenticate;
  print $pamh->pam_strerror($res),"\n" unless $res == PAM_SUCCESS();
```

Comment: Yeah, ok, but the question was about a CGI script written in Python.

Answer (score 1):

To more specifically answer:
"Is it possible to create a bash script that will test a given username and password combination against the registred user on the host?"

Yes.

```
#!/bin/bash
uid=`id -u`

if [ $uid -ne 0 ]; then 
    echo "You must be root to run this"
    exit 1
fi

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "You must supply a username to check - ($# supplied)"
    exit 1
fi

username=$1
salt=`grep $username /etc/shadow | awk -F: ' {print substr($2,4,8)}'`

if [ "$salt" != "" ]; then

        newpass=`openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt`
        grep $username  /etc/shadow | grep -q  $newpass && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"

fi
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I am seeing that you are checking an existing shadow password against the shadow password but where is the hashing involved here?

Comment: I tested and it don't work

Comment: Bad idea! You're assuming that your program is running as root, or at least as the `shadow` group, which is very strongly not recommended for a CGI: you'd need another layer of privilege escalation. And you're assuming a particular password hashing algorithm (one supported by openssl) and password storage location (`/etc/shadow` as opposed to e.g. NIS or LDAP) which may or may not be the one actually used for that particular user.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access, and are using md5 passwords, and you just need to compare passwords, then you can use the perl [Crypt::PasswdMD5](http://search.cpan.org/~luismunoz/Crypt-PasswdMD5-1.3/PasswdMD5.pm) module.   Take the MD5 Hash from /etc/shadow, strip the $1$, and then split on the remaining $.  Field 1 = Salt, Field 2 = crypted text.  Then hash the text input into your CGI, compare that to the crypted text, and Bob's your uncle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Crypt::PasswdMD5;

my $user                = $ARGV[0];
my $plain               = $ARGV[1];
my $check               = qx{ grep $user /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2 };
chomp($check);
my($salt,$md5txt)       = $check =~ m/\$1\$([^\$].+)\$(.*)$/;
my $pass                = unix_md5_crypt($plain, $salt);

if ( "$check" eq "$pass" ) {
        print "OK","\n";
} else {
        print "ERR","\n";
}
```

Comment: plain and simple :-). This will work as long as /etc/passwd uses md5 hashing.Incase the authentication (nsswitch) is different for the system, then pam modules are best to use.

Comment: Bad idea! You're assuming that your program is running as root, or at least as the `shadow` group, which is very strongly not recommended for a CGI: you'd need another layer of privilege escalation. And you're assuming a particular password hashing algorithm (MD5 and not bcrypt or other recommended algorithm) and password storage location (`/etc/shadow` as opposed to e.g. NIS or LDAP) which may or may not be the one actually used for that particular user.

Answer (score 0):

After some search I wrote this C program that can be used from script

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <shadow.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct spwd *pwd;
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage:\n\t%s [username] [password]\n", basename(argv[0]));
        return 1;
    } else if (getuid() == 0) {
        pwd = getspnam(argv[1]);
        return strcmp(crypt(argv[2], pwd->sp_pwdp), pwd->sp_pwdp);
    } else {
        printf("You need to be root\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You compile it with:

```
gcc -Wall password_check.c /usr/lib/libcrypt.a -o check_passwd
```

You can use it as

```
sudo ./check_passwd <user> <password> && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

Comment: Bad idea! You're assuming that your program is running as root, or at least as the `shadow` group, which is very strongly not recommended for a CGI: you'd need another layer of privilege escalation. And you're assuming a particular password hashing algorithm (one supported by openssl) and password storage location (`/etc/shadow` as opposed to e.g. NIS or LDAP) which may or may not be the one actually used for that particular user. Use PAM, it knows its job.

Comment: Yes I know, but thought that this is not posible with without root. All other solutions use root as well, exept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are using CGI in python, its probably appropriate to assume that you are using Apache as your httpd server. If so, leave the authentication process of your program to Apache and only let the authenticated people execute your cgi scripts/programs.

There are ample modules which can do authentication for you on Apache, it really depends on what kind of authentication mechanism you are looking for. The way you quoted in the question seems to be related to the local host account authentication based on /etc/passwd,shadow files. Module that comes to my quick search regarding this is `mod_auth_shadow`. Advantage is that you are allowing someone authoritative (running on privilege port 80) to authenticate the user/password for you and you can rely on authenticated information of the user to run the commands on behalf of the user, if needed.

Good links to start:

http://adam.shand.net/archives/2008/apache_tips_and_tricks/#index5h2

http://mod-auth-shadow.sourceforge.net/

http://www.howtoforge.com/apache_mod_auth_shadow_debian_ubuntu

Another approach is to use SuEXEc module of Apache, which executes processes(cgi programs) on behalf of the authenticated user.

Comment: This CGI script is JSON-RPC service called via Ajax and I need method login that return a token, token should be returned if login succeed. So basicaly every user need to be able to execute that script.

Answer (score 0):

This code using PAM worked for me:

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_misc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define custom PAM conversation function
int custom_converation(int num_msg, const struct pam_message** msg, struct pam_response** resp, void* appdata_ptr)
{
    // Provide password for the PAM conversation response that was passed into appdata_ptr
    struct pam_response* reply = (struct pam_response* )malloc(sizeof(struct pam_response));
    reply[0].resp = (char*)appdata_ptr;
    reply[0].resp_retcode = 0;

    *resp = reply;

    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        // Set up a custom PAM conversation passing in authentication password
        char* password = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
        strcpy(password, argv[2]);        
        struct pam_conv pamc = { custom_converation, password };
        pam_handle_t* pamh; 
        int retval;

        // Start PAM - just associate with something simple like the "whoami" command
        if ((retval = pam_start("whoami", argv[1], &pamc, &pamh)) == PAM_SUCCESS)
        {
            // Authenticate the user
            if ((retval = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0)) == PAM_SUCCESS) 
                fprintf(stdout, "OK\n"); 
            else 
                fprintf(stderr, "FAIL: pam_authentication failed.\n"); 

            // All done
            pam_end(pamh, 0); 
            return retval; 
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "FAIL: pam_start failed.\n"); 
            return retval;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "FAIL: expected two arguments for user name and password.\n"); 
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: Could you add some context information to make it "feel" more like an answer?

Answer (score -3):

The best thing you can do, if you need a script to login to a host, is configure a ssh key between the hosts.

Link: http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/

I pretty much lifted this from the page

---

First, install OpenSSH on two UNIX machines, hurly and burly. This works best using DSA keys and SSH2 by default as far as I can tell. All the other HOWTOs I've seen seem to deal with RSA keys and SSH1, and the instructions not surprisingly fail to work with SSH2.
On each machine type ssh somemachine.example.com and make a connection with your regular password. This will create a .ssh dir in your home directory with the proper perms.
On your primary machine where you want your secret keys to live (let's say hurly), type

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

This will prompt you for a secret passphrase. If this is your primary identity key, make sure to use a good passphrase. If this works right you will get two files called id_dsa and id_dsa.pub in your .ssh dir. Note: it is possible to just press the enter key when prompted for a passphrase, which will make a key with no passphrase. This is a Bad Idea ™ for an identity key, so don't do it! See below for uses of keys without passphrases.

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub burly:.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Copy the id_dsa.pub file to the other host's .ssh dir with the name authorized_keys2.   Now burly is ready to accept your ssh key. How to tell it which keys to use? The ssh-add command will do it. For a test, type

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add < /dev/null && bash'
```

This will start the ssh-agent, add your default identity(prompting you for your passphrase), and spawn a bash shell. From this new shell you should be able to:

```
ssh burly
```

You should be able to log in

Comment: While this is true, it does not appear to be relevant to the question, which is about an application accessed through a web browser.